# Excel Formula If then

Tags: excel-formula

I am new to excel and looking to see how to do this formula correctly.  On A1 I have the data texts Promoters, Passives and Detractors.  I am not sure why my formula is not working.

[image]

What I wanted to happen, is make a formula where in if on cell B1 Promoters, then RANDBETWEEN 9 or 10, If Passive then Rand Between 7 and 8 and If Detractors, then RANDBETWEEN 0 to 6.

Comment: Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be read aloud or copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Comment: @TobySpeight Will do! Thanks

Comment: @herrbischoff Thanks! Everyone needs to start somewhere right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, perhaps you want:

```
IF(A1="PROMOTERS",RANDBETWEEN(9,10),IF(A1="PASSIVE",RANDBETWEEN(7,8),IF(A1="DETRACTORS",RANDBETWEEN(0,6),"Error")))
```

[image]

If I followed correctly.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! This is what I needed.